# Django Admin Interface ReadOnly

Tags: django

In the admin interface - is it possible to set a field to readonly, but also set the value?  For example, I am building a CRM and a organization will have a program.  I want the user who is creating a program to always use the organization that they belong to.

example:

Program
name
organizationId

User
name
organizationId

I want the code to be something like

```
class Program(models.adminmodel):

readonly = ["organization"]

organization = user.organization
```

class Organization(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
state = models.ForeignKey(State)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

class OrganizationUser(models.Model):

```
organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

user is same table as default in django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can make admin field read only

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

```
 class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
     fields = ("organization", "field2")
     readonly_fields = ("organization", )

     def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
         obj.organization = request.user.organization
         obj.save()
```

Comment: Hi Ramast - Thank you, but this is not what I am asking.  I am asking if you can set the value of the readonly field to be the users organizatoin

Comment: Updated the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks - DO you know how ti can make this part of it work 

Organization = OrganizationUser.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)

I need to just get the Organizationid from Organizationuser

Comment: Assuming your user model has `organization = models.ForiegnKey(Organziation)` then you can get organization id by accessing `user.organization_id`

Comment: I use a third table --- User, Organizatoin, OrganizatoinUsers

Comment: If you can show me the 3 models I can be more helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102087/discussion-between-jeremy-lewallen-and-ramast).